# Middleware redirect with value

Tags: php, http, laravel-5, middleware

I'm building project on laravel 5 and at the moment I'm bit confused. I check if user is loggedin in my middleware. It he is not, I want to generate a link, specially for unique user like this:

```
$code = str_random(32);
return redirect()->guest('user/review/information', [$code]);
```

I'm getting error:

```
The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/user/review/information/{slug}', ['as'=>'review-additional', 'uses'=>'ReviewController@getReviewInformation']);
```

Could someone explain me, what am I doing wrong? Or bring any suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is the HTTP status code, you should use...

```
return redirect()->guest('user/review/information/' . $code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `redirect()->guest()`?

As i see, you should just

```
redirect()->route('review-additional', ['slug' => $code]);
```

Comment: After loging in, there will be a redirect back. Thats how route->quest() works.